# Como usar openweathermap

Tags: android

Hola amigos quiero integrar en mi App una ventana en donde me muestre una lista la predicción del clima de una ciudad, y quiero que quede mas o menos así [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He indagado y encontré que hay un servicio llamado Openweathermap, me he registrado pero no entiendo que debo de hacer después de registrarme, la página me dice que siga estos pasos y no se en donde encontrar el ID que pide la URL

> API call:
>
> http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=524901&APPID={APIKEY}
>   Parameters:
>
> APPID {APIKEY} is your unique API key  Example of API call:
>
> api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=524901&APPID=1111111111

Si alguien lo ha integrado a sus App me gustaría saber en que página puedo encontrar información de como implementarlo, saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vas bien.

El ID lo debes generar con tu misma cuenta. Lo puedes generar aqui :

https://home.openweathermap.org/api_keys

Una vez tengas el ID, solo te queda utilizar el WebService, mas documentación aqui:

https://openweathermap.org/current

Comment: ya tengo la KEY pero mi duda es que va en la parte de "id=" y en "APPID="

Comment: me puedes pasar la url de donde sacaste esta dirección **api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=XXXXX&APPID=YYYYY** . La cuestión es que en la documentación oficial no encuentro esa url.

Comment: http://openweathermap.org/appid

Comment: Perfecto ya comprendo. En el primer Id=XXXX, XXXX viene a ser el identificador del lugar de donde quieres obtener el clima, Ejemplo : 524901 = Moscow, y pues el segundo es tu APPID.

Comment: Puedes encontrar el listado de Ids por region aqui : http://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/ -> **city.list.json.gz**

Comment: Vale ya me generó el servicio, ahora solo quedaría consumirlo con la URL que me generó y adaptar los datos de acuerdo a mi criterio verdad?

Comment: Exactamente. Suerte :D

Comment: Muchas gracias :D

Comment: asi es busca el id de la ciudad y el appid es el que generas con tu cuenta, ahora si alguien me puede decir como convierto la respuesta en que me da la api en ingles a español? es lo unico que me esta faltando...